# MM5452 with 4 digit parallel 7-segment LCD display

Tags: lcd, parallel, 7segmentdisplay

I have a question regarding the backplane connection for the MM5452.  From this data sheet:

[MM5452/MM5453 Liquid Crystal Display Drivers](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/snls367c/snls367c.pdf)

It says that the backplane pins on the MM5452 connects to a BP pin on the display.  Here is my display: [Varitronix VI-422](http://www.varitronix.com/prod_pdf/VI-422.pdf)

I don't see a BP pin.  Are the common pins (Pin 1 and 40) my backplane pins?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you are correct. Pins 1 & 40 are marked "**COM**" which sounds like Common. The LCD Driver puts out an AC signal to the segments to be seen, and this signal is with respect to the "Back-plane" or "Common".